# What's wrong with my mod rewrite for GEOIP based on location?

Tags: redirects, mod-rewrite, geotargeting

I'm a bit of a newb in modrewrite but used it successfully on my server before.

I successful installed the module on my apache server and tested out with PHP test page(it correctly returned my area code) so I decided to test it out on a site and have it redirect to another page on it.

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat Standard
GeoIPDBFile /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat Standard

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_AREA_CODE} ^847  
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.teetimelawncare\.com/lawncare\.html$1 [NC,QSA]
```

I simply get 500 Internal Server Errors every single time. Any idea why?

EDIT: I was having errors with my AddType x-mapp php5 line in my .htaccess file. Removing that allows it to work.

Comment: Have you checked apache's error_log? That should be your first step to get to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To isolate the problem, first try it without the redirect. If it still doesn't work, then make sure that the `httpd` user (e.g. `nobody`) has read access to the GeoIP database files, as covered in the Troubleshooting section [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/#Troubleshooting).

Also make sure that each line in your *.htaccess* file or main server config ends in a [newline](http://answers.stanford.edu/solution/im-trying-use-htaccess-file-web-auth-i-get-500-server-error-message), and remove the spacing before `RewriteEngine On`.

Lastly, you might want to use `IndexCache`, which would reduce the number of lookups and read/write access for a large database file like GeoIP City - see the example [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/#File_and_Caching_Directives).